# Show active navigation for current page with php

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to use use `$current_url = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);` to determine which page I am on, considering my navigation (html) is stored in a php file and is included in every page. This is the code I use to determine which navigation option should be active:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/no-background.css">

<ul>
<?php
    $current_url = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    $active = "class=\"active\"";
?>
<?php if ($current_url == "globaluser.php") { ?>
    <li <?php echo $active;?> > <?php } ?> <a href="globaluser.php?Agent=<?php echo $Agent;?>">Overview</a></li>
<?php if ($current_url == "search.php") { ?>
    <li <?php echo $active;?> > <?php } ?> <a href="search.php?Agent=<?php echo $Agent?>">Add new client</a></li>
<?php if ($current_url == "viewadmins.php") { ?>
    <li <?php echo $active;?> > <?php } ?> <a href="viewadmins.php?Agent=<?php echo $Agent?>">View admins</a></li>
    <li class="border-right"><a href="emails.php?Agent=<?php echo $Agent?>">E-mails</a></li>
    <li class="right border-right"><a href="logout.php"><?php echo $Agent?></a>
        <ul class="drop1">
            <li><a href="earnings.php?Agent=<?php echo $Agent?>">Earnings</a></li>
            <li id="hover-trigger"><a href="#">Change Password</a>
                <ul class="drop2">
                    <li>
                        <form action="changepass.php?Agent=<?php echo $Agent?>" method="POST">
                            <input type="password" name="1" placeholder="Enter new password">
                            <input type="password" name="2" placeholder="Repeat new password">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                            <input type="submit" name="changepw" class="button" value="Change">
                        </form>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        <li>
            <form action="logout.php">
                <input type="submit" class="button" value="Log out">
            </form>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

But it doesn't work. It shows the active page as active, however, it shows 2 pages as simple hyperlinks. This is what it looks like:

[image: Navigation errors]

Does anyone have any clue as to why this happens? It works for 2 but fails for 2, exact same code?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```
<li <?php echo ($current_url == "globaluser.php") ? $active : ''?> ><a href="globaluser.php?Agent=<?php echo $Agent;?>">Overview</a></li>
```

because right now you're conditioning the presence of the opening `<li>` tag

Comment: That was the trick, thank you. Just one question, the syntax you used.. I understand the IF in the brackets, but I dont understand:

`? $active : ''` why the question mark and everything after active? 
It worked, you saved me!

Comment: @koala_dev is using the ternary operator. It is a shorter way to write expressions if you are assigning one of two values based on a condition. For example instead of `if($foo == 'bar') { $letter = 'a'; } 
else{ $letter = 'z'; }` You can do: `$letter = ($foo == 'bar') ? 'a' : 'z'; `

Comment: @SamFisher you could also write `<?php if($current_url == "globaluser.php"){echo $active} ?>` but personally I find using the ternary operator more readable than a single line if, just note that the else part (what comes after the `:`) is mandatory and that's why I added an empty string

Comment: Yeah I liked how the code is short that's why I asked about it =) Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

You are using `<?php } ?>` at wrong place.
It should be after
 `<a href="search.php?Agent=<?php echo $Agent?>">Add new client</a></li>`

Updated code is as follows:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/no-background.css">

<ul>
<?php
    $current_url = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    echo $current_url;
    $active = "class=\"active\"";
?>
<?php if ($current_url == "globaluser.php") { ?>
    <li <?php echo $active;?> > <?php } ?> <a href="globaluser.php?Agent=<?php echo $Agent;?>">Overview</a></li>
<?php if ($current_url == "search.php") { ?>
    <li <?php echo $active;?> > <a href="search.php?Agent=<?php echo $Agent?>">Add new client</a></li> <?php } ?> 
<?php if ($current_url == "viewadmins.php") { ?>
    <li <?php echo $active;?> >  <a href="viewadmins.php?Agent=<?php echo $Agent?>">View admins</a></li><?php } ?>
    <li class="border-right"><a href="emails.php?Agent=<?php echo $Agent?>">E-mails</a></li>
    <li class="right border-right"><a href="logout.php"><?php echo $Agent?></a>
        <ul class="drop1">

            <li><a href="earnings.php?Agent=<?php echo $Agent?>">Earnings</a></li>

            <li id="hover-trigger"><a href="#">Change Password</a>

                <ul class="drop2">
                    <li>
                        <form action="changepass.php?Agent=<?php echo $Agent?>" method="POST">
                            <input type="password" name="1" placeholder="Enter new password">
                            <input type="password" name="2" placeholder="Repeat new password">
                    </li>
                    <li>

                            <input type="submit" name="changepw" class="button" value="Change">
                        </form>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <form action="logout.php">
                <input type="submit" class="button" value="Log out">
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: I was actually conditioning the opening of the li itself, as mentioned above. But thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use preg_replace() to add `class="active"`

```
ob_start();
echo '<ul>
  <li><a href="page1.php">Page 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="page2.php">Page 2</a></li>
  </ul>';
$output = ob_get_clean();
$pattern = '~<li><a href="'.$url.'">~';
$replacement = '<li class="active"><a href="'.$url.'">';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $output);
```